# Does valgrind consider execution of memory a write?

Tags: debugging, gdb, valgrind, watch, memory-access

I have a JIT. I set up a watchpoint (`watch` -- so it should trigger only on a write) to the jitted code of a function (all of it) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022441/2104472). And I provide `--vgdb=full` to valgrind which means all instructions have to be instrumented and I should see execution stopped precisely where the stop happened.

However the watchpoint triggers several times in the middle of the function being watched. I noticed that the instructions at which execution stops are basic block entry points (they all follow either a `jump` or a `call` or it's the first instruction of my function).

I don't see actual write to the watched memory upon the watchpoint firing. So does valgrind consider execution of this memory (some of it) a write? Or is it some other valgrind weirdness, or is it just me?

Please, clarify.

My valgrind version is 3.10.0.SVN, gdb is 7.7.1 (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2).

Answer (score 0):

Executing some code should not be considered as a write by
valgrind gdbserver.
Some valgrind trace arguments (-v -v -v -d -d -d) might give an idea
about what happens.